# How do you properly include a conditional css file for IE in Rails 3.1+ (asset pipeline) and haml?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, asset-pipeline

The solutions I've searched online do not work.  I currently have rails 3.1 and haml installed. The `ie.css` file is located under `app/assets/stylesheets` right next to the `application.css`.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
%html
  %head 
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all' 
    <!–[if (IE)]><!–>
    <link href=”ie.css” media=”screen” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />
    <!–<![endif]–>
```

application.rb:

```
   config.assets.precompile += %w(ie.css)
```

application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/[if IE] 
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'ie'
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  It is still not able to differentiate between IE and the other web browsers.

Comment: Yes, it does.  The HTML code will be present in all browsers, but only IE will interpret it.

Comment: Both firefox and chrome are using the css in ie.css. So no, this does not work at least in my environment.  Is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: Ah!  Maybe I missed it before, but your application.css manifest include `*= require_tree .`.  That is going to bundle up ie.css as well.  You need to remove `*= require_tree .` from your manifest and load the files you want all the time individually.

Comment: This is not supported anymore https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx